# The path does not reach the end node in my A* algorithm

Tags: a-star, netlogo

Following on from [How to speed up least-cost path model at large spatial extents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202199/how-to-speed-up-least-cost-path-model-at-large-spatial-extents), I tried to code an A* algorithm in Netlogo to increase my least-cost path model at large spatial extents. Here is my code:

```
to findPath [ID-start-node ID-end-node]

 let currentNodesInList [ ]
 let current-node node ID-start-node
 let end-node node ID-end-node
 ask current-node [ set color red]
 ask end-node [ set color red]

 set currentNodesInList lput current-node currentNodesInList

 while [not member? end-node currentNodesInList] [

 ask current-node [ 

 foreach sort nodes-on neighbors [ 

  ask ? [set f-value [link-cost] of link ([who] of current-node) ([who] of ?) + distance end-node] ]  

  let next-current-node min-one-of [nodes-on neighbors] of current-node [f-value]
  ask link ([who] of current-node) ([who] of next-current-node) [set color red]
  set current-node next-current-node

  set currentNodesInList lput current-node currentNodesInList] ]
end
```

When ID-start-node and ID-end-node are close in the landscape, the code seems to work. However, when the distance between ID-start-node and ID-end-node is higher, the path does not reach the ID-end-node (see figure below; but sometimes, the code works).

In the figure, ID-start-node and ID-end-node are represented by a red start and the path is drawn in red.

[image]

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Just a minor coding tip: it's hardly ever necessary or best to look things up using who numbers. Almost every time you're using a who number for something, there's a better way. So for example `link ([who] of current-node) ([who] of ?)` can be shortened to `[link-with current-node] of ?`.

Comment: As for your actual question, I tried, but I was unable to spot the bug just by looking at your code. Not sure what to suggest other than applying standard debugging techniques, for example adding print statements to your code so it tells you more what about it's doing. Then try and spot the place where it first goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks very much Seth. I think that the path does not reach the end node because the path turns back (takes a step backwards at each time). So I am not sure that the calculation of f.value `[link-cost] of link ([who] of current-node) ([who] of ?) + distance end-node` is correct ? Is f.value equal to link cost between the start node and its neighbor node + distance between the start node and end node in the A* algorithm ? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: That sounds like a good question for you to investigate yourself using NetLogo itself. You can ask the question by adding `show` or `print` statements to your code and seeing whether the numbers match your intentions or not.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a look at this model in the NetLogo users community:

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/community/Astardemo1

It implements a simple procedure (find-a-path) that takes in the source and the target patches as parameters and returns a list of patches (which is one of the shortest paths from the source patch to the destination patch) using the A-star shortest path finding algorithm.

Also you might try turning off world wrapping.

Comment: That does not seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 3):

A* has to have a way to back up a try old paths if it runs into a deadend, or something that seems inefficient. Your implementation just keeps going on a single path. While your way is definitely the most natural way to implement path finding, and much simpler, that could be why you're running into problems.

Here's an implementation I came up with. It uses patches directly rather than links, which actually seems like it would be better for you. Just give it a patch task that reports the cost of traveling across that patch and the source and target patches. I'm not super happy with it: real A* uses a heap to keep track of how good it think each possible path should be. I had to emulate the heap with a list, so it won't be as fast as true A*. If others see improvements, feel free to edit my answer or make suggestions in the comments! Anyway, here it is:

```
to-report find-path [ get-cost source destination ]
  let paths (list (list source))
  let estimated-costs (list [distance destination ] of source)
  let path first paths

  let visited patch-set source
  let encountered patch-set source

  while [ source != destination ] [
    let estimated-cost min estimated-costs
    let path-index position estimated-cost estimated-costs
    set path item path-index paths
    set source last path
    let path-cost estimated-cost - [ distance destination ] of source
    let source-cost [ runresult get-cost ] of source

    set paths remove-item path-index paths
    set estimated-costs remove-item path-index estimated-costs

    set visited (patch-set source visited)

    ask [ neighbors with [ not member? self visited ] ] of source [
      let patch-cost runresult get-cost
      let step-cost distance source * (patch-cost + source-cost) / 2
      let est-cost path-cost + step-cost + distance destination

      let add? true

      if member? self encountered [
        let other-path false
        foreach paths [
          if last ? = self [
            set other-path ?
          ]
        ]
        if other-path != false [
          let other-path-index position other-path paths
          let other-path-cost item other-path-index estimated-costs
          ifelse other-path-cost < est-cost [
            set add? false
          ] [
            set paths remove-item other-path-index paths
            set estimated-costs remove-item other-path-index estimated-costs
          ]
        ]
      ]

      if add? [
        set estimated-costs fput est-cost estimated-costs
        set paths fput (lput self path) paths

        set encountered (patch-set self encountered)
      ]
    ]    
  ]
  report path
end
```

If `cost` is a patch variable that contains the cost of traveling across that patch, then you'd call it like so: `find-path task [ cost ] source-patch target-patch`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much Megh and Bryan for your responses. Thanks to your help, I coded an A* algorithm that seems to work. My code calculates the path between all patches situated at polygon edges (to increase speed up simulation) and draws the least-cost path among all these patches. However, I am disappointed because I find that my code is yet too slow (e.g. 2 min to draw the path on the above figure). Is there another solution to reduce the number of patches to test? Have I to post a new question? Of course, I can give my code. Thanks for your help.