# Pathfinding on Netlogo - Robotic lawn mower simulation project

Tags: netlogo, path-finding

I am trying to simulate a robotic lawn mower on Netlogo. My goals were that :

- It goes randomly on green patches (grass) to cut them (green turns grey).
- It finds its way home to recharge itself when the battery is low.
- It does not go away the defined perimeter (garden) narrowed by red patches and goes arround obstacles placed by user with mouse clicks.

I have now a working code for my two first objectives(thanks to Luke !).

However making the lawn mower respect my whish of not going on red patches is getting complicated after getting in the `to check death` step.
Indeed it seems that it does not take into account my previous orders in the `to move-cars` step.

Some people told me that if I wanted to make it navigate around the walls it would be actually pretty involved and will require some kind of pathfinding.

Through my research I found some documentation about what is called an A*.
I understood the concept of the algorithm well but its translation on Netlogo is very difficult for me. What I did without a course so far was pretty basic, based on existing codes and following the advice I was given. But from now on, adapting an A* for my code makes me lose my hair. I hope to be able to finally understand the intricacies of Netlogo by understanding how pathfinding would be implemented in my code.
I understand that some people will not want to dwell on explaining how it works. I just hope to find someone patient enough to explain to me how things work with an A* step by step.

Thanks a lot

Here's my code :

```
breed [cars car]
cars-own [target charging? charge-time car-energy]

breed [houses house]
to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-cars
  setup-house
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [set pcolor green] ;; Setup grass patches
  ask patches with [
    pxcor = max-pxcor or
    pxcor = min-pxcor or
    pycor = max-pycor or
    pycor = min-pycor ] [
    set pcolor red ;; Setup garden perimeter
  ]
end

to setup-cars

  set-default-shape cars "car"
create-cars 1 [
    setxy 8 8 ;; Place the lawn mower near the house
    set target one-of houses
    set charging? false
    set car-energy energy
  ]
end

to setup-house
  set-default-shape houses "house"
  ask patch 7 8 [sprout-houses 1]
end

to place-walls
  if mouse-down? [
    ask patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor [ set pcolor red ]
    display ;; Permits the user to place red patches as new obstacles in garden.
  ]
end


to go
  move-cars
  cut-grass
  check-death ;; Verify % battery.
  tick
end

to move-cars
  ask cars [
    ifelse charging? [
      set charge-time charge-time + 1 ;; Counts the time spent to charge
      if charge-time > 15 [ ;; Defined charge time here
        set car-energy 1000
        set charging? false
        set charge-time 0
      ]
    ] [
      ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = red
      [ lt random-float 360 ]   ;; See a red patch ahead : turn left randomly
      [ fd 1 ]                  ;; Otherwise, its safe to go foward.
      set car-energy car-energy - 1
    ]
  ]
end

to cut-grass
  ask cars [
    if pcolor = green [ ;; cut grass (green patches go grey)
      set pcolor gray
    ]
  ]
end

to check-death ;; checking battery level
  ask cars [
    ifelse car-energy >= 300
    [ set label "Energy ok" ]
    [ set label "Low Energy, returning to base"
      set target min-one-of houses [distance myself]
      face target
      ifelse distance target < 1
      [ move-to target
        set charging? true
        set label "Charging"
      ]
      [ fd 1 ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23438674